# WSO2 API Manager: Change Message Type from SOAP to XML

Tags: wso2

I have an internal webservice exposed in SOAP/HTTP. What I am trying to achieve using API manager is to expose my internal SOAP based webservice over different protocols like XML, JSON etc.

Does WSO2 API manager have that capability.

Thanks and Regards
Privin Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to transform the incoming message into a different format for the backend. This can be done using the underlying ESB capabilities of the API Manager - there are actualy several ways.  IMHO, the easiest way to do this is with Mediation Extensions.  For information on adding a Mediation Extension to an API, please see the documentation here:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+Mediation+Extensions